# Cofusing Program Crash During Copy

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

Could someone give me some help figuring out why my program is crashing every time I try to run it? The crash seems to happen during any of the Copy/Paste lines that I have, so:

1. `ShRef.Range(ShRef.Cells(ShRef.Rows.Count, pCol).End(xlUp), ShRef.Cells(1, pCol)).Copy Destination:=ShWork.Columns(outCol)`
2. `ShRef.Range(ShRef.Cells(ShRef.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp), ShRef.Cells(oneOrTwo, 1)).Copy Destination:=ShWork.Cells(rowCounter, 1)`
3. `ShRef.Range(ShRef.Cells(ShRef.Rows.Count, pCol).End(xlUp), ShRef.Cells(oneOrTwo, pCol)).Copy Destination:=ShWork.Cells(rowCounter, 2)`
4. `Set myShape = pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteHTML, Link:=msoFalse)`

I'm really not sure why this is happening, because the same commands worked before. Any help is appreciated, and here is the rest of my code:

```
Public Sub averageScoreRelay()
    ' 1. Run from PPT and open an Excel file
    ' 2. Start at slide 1 and find a box that contains the words "iq_", if it has those words then it will have numbers after it like so "iq_43" or "iq_43, iq_56,iq_72".
    ' 3. find those words and numbers in the opened Excel file after splitting and re-formating string.
    ' 3. Copy column into a new sheets and repeat for all "iq_'s" until sheets 2 has a table.
    ' 4. Copy table from xl Paste Table into ppt
    ' 5. Do this for every slide

    'Timer start
    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
    StartTime = Timer


    'Create variables
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ShRef As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ShWork As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim pptPres As Object
    Dim colNumb As Long
    Dim rowNumb As Long

    ' Create new excel instance and open relevant workbook
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    'xlApp.Visible = True 'Make Excel visible
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("c:/filepath", True, False, , , , True, Notify:=False) 'Open relevant workbook
    If xlWB Is Nothing Then                      ' may not need this if statement. check later.
        MsgBox ("Error retrieving Average Score Report, Check file path")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Find # of iq's in workbook
    Set ShRef = xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    colNumb = ShRef.Cells(1, ShRef.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    rowNumb = ShRef.Cells(ShRef.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim IQRef() As String
    Dim iCol As Long

    ReDim IQRef(colNumb)
    ' capture IQ refs locally
    For iCol = 2 To colNumb
        IQRef(iCol) = ShRef.Cells(1, iCol).Value
    Next iCol

    'Create a new blank Sheet in excel, should be "Sheet2"
    xlWB.Worksheets.Add After:=xlWB.ActiveSheet
    Set ShWork = xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    'Make pptPres the ppt active
    Set pptPres = PowerPoint.ActivePresentation

    'Create variables for the slide loop
    Dim pptSlide As Slide
    Dim Shpe As Shape
    Dim pptText As String
    Dim iq_Array As Variant
    Dim arrayLoop As Long
    Dim myShape As Object
    Dim outCol As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim hasIQs As Boolean
    Dim checkStr As String
    Dim pCol As Long
    Dim checkOne
    Dim iQRefArray As Variant
    Dim iQRefString As String
    Dim checkRefStr As String
    Dim rowCounter As Long
    Dim oneOrTwo As Long


    'Loop through each pptSlide and check for IQ text box, grab avgScore values and create pptTable
    For Each pptSlide In pptPres.Slides

        i = 0
        pptSlide.Select

        'searches through shapes in the slide
        For Each Shpe In pptSlide.Shapes

            If Not Shpe.HasTextFrame Then GoTo nextShpe 'boom, one less nested If statement
            If Not Shpe.TextFrame.HasText Then GoTo nextShpe ' boom, another nested If statement bites the dust

            outCol = 1

            'Set pptText as the Text in the box, then make it lowercase and trim Spaces and Enters
            pptText = Shpe.TextFrame.TextRange
            pptText = LCase(Replace(pptText, " ", vbNullString))
            pptText = Replace(Replace(Replace(pptText, vbCrLf, vbNullString), vbCr, vbNullString), vbLf, vbNullString)


            'Identify if within text there is "iq_"
            If InStr(1, pptText, "iq_") <= 0 Then GoTo nextShpe

            'set iq_Array as an array of the split iq's
            iq_Array = Split(pptText, ",")

            checkOne = iq_Array(0)

            hasIQs = Left(checkOne, 3) = "iq_"

            If hasIQs Then
                ' paste inital column into temporary worksheet
                ShRef.Columns(1).Copy Destination:=ShWork.Columns(1)
            End If

            ' loop for each iq_ in the array
            For arrayLoop = LBound(iq_Array) To UBound(iq_Array)
                ' Take copy of potential ref and adjust to standard if required
                checkStr = iq_Array(arrayLoop)
                If hasIQs And Left(checkStr, 3) <> "iq_" Then checkStr = "iq_" & checkStr
                rowCounter = 2

                ' Look for existence of corresponding column in local copy array
                For iCol = 2 To colNumb

                    pCol = 0

                    'format the numbers in the excel file to fit code needs. The full form for iq_'s in the excel database is: "iq_66_01__A_"
                    iQRefString = Left(IQRef(iCol), Len(IQRef(iCol)) - 1)
                    iQRefArray = Replace(iQRefString, "__", "_")
                    iQRefArray = Split(iQRefArray, "_")
                    checkRefStr = "iq_" & iQRefArray(1)

                    If checkStr = checkRefStr Then
                        pCol = iCol
                    End If

                    If pCol > 0 Then

                        If iQRefArray(3) = "A" Then
                            ' Paste the corresponding column into the forming table
                            outCol = outCol + 1
                            ShRef.Range(ShRef.Cells(ShRef.Rows.Count, pCol).End(xlUp), ShRef.Cells(1, pCol)).Copy Destination:=ShWork.Columns(outCol)
                        ElseIf iQRefArray(3) = "AT" Then
                            outCol = outCol + 1
                            If outCol = 3 Then
                                rowCounter = rowCounter + rowNumb + 1
                                oneOrTwo = 2
                            ElseIf outCol <> 2 Then
                                rowCounter = rowCounter + rowNumb
                                oneOrTwo = 2
                            Else
                                rowCounter = 1
                                oneOrTwo = 1
                            End If
                            ShRef.Range(ShRef.Cells(ShRef.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp), ShRef.Cells(oneOrTwo, 1)).Copy Destination:=ShWork.Cells(rowCounter, 1)
                            ShRef.Range(ShRef.Cells(ShRef.Rows.Count, pCol).End(xlUp), ShRef.Cells(oneOrTwo, pCol)).Copy Destination:=ShWork.Cells(rowCounter, 2)
                        End If

                    End If

                Next iCol

                If outCol > 1 Then               'data was added
                    ' Copy table
                    ShWork.UsedRange.Copy        ' all the data added to ShWork gets copied

tryAgain:

                    ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewNormal
                    ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Activate

                    Set myShape = pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteHTML, Link:=msoFalse)

                    On Error GoTo tryAgain
                    On Error GoTo clrSht

                    'Set position:
                    myShape.Left = -200
                    myShape.Top = 150 + i
                    i = i + 150

clrSht:

                    ' Clear data from temporary sheet
                    ShWork.UsedRange.Clear

                    rowCounter = 1
                    outCol = 1

                End If

            Next arrayLoop

nextShpe:

        Next Shpe

    Next pptSlide

    ShWork.Delete
    xlWB.Close
    xlApp.Quit

    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True

    'End Timer
    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
    MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the specific error message? Can you make a [mcve] that reproduces the issue? That's quite a lot of code...

Comment: what is the exact line that it crashes ? can you put a breakpoint and find that out.you can also try to comment that line and see if it gives any other error.

Comment: @Mat'sMug there is no specific message, I just get the spinning wheel and the program doesn't respond

Comment: Try sticking a `DoEvents` before the `Next pptSlide` line

Comment: @ImranMalek so I've tried different databases, and stepped through the code. The program crashed at all four copy/paste lines when stepping through it. So, for some databases the program would run fine until slide 40 and then the program would crash on one of the four mentioned copy/paste lines. Then on another database the program would crash on the first slide with one of the other four mentioned copy/paste lines.

Comment: "the same commands worked before" - before what exactly?  Has something changed or are you doing things differently?

Comment: @Mat'sMug did not work :/. I tried sticking one in front of every paste as well just to see what would happen and that didn't work either. It's currently crashing on Set myShape = paste....

Comment: You need to [edit] your question, it's quite unclear as it stands. You talk of a crash, but there's no crash, only an appareny stall. Also try to reduce the amount of code and boil it down to the smallest possible snippet that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I found the culprit, thanks everyone for your help :). Answer is posted.

Answer (score 1):

Every copy and paste option was crashing, but that's because this original culprit was in there:

`ShRef.Range(ShRef.Cells(ShRef.Rows.Count, pCol).End(xlUp), ShRef.Cells(1, pCol)).Copy Destination:=ShWork.Columns(outCol)`

Notice that it's printing to the entire column, therefore through multiple iterations, Sheet2 would have over 30million cells of value. Then when the program went to copy all contents from Sheet2 and paste onto PowerPoint, it would immediately crash.

I've fixed it by writting:

`ShRef.Range(ShRef.Cells(ShRef.Rows.Count, pCol).End(xlUp), ShRef.Cells(1, pCol)).Copy Destination:=ShWork.Cells(,outCol)`